# how to compare two date columns in python

Tags: python, date

still learning python and have a previous SAS background. Want to compare two date columns and have a string column based on the result.

example is below

[image]

essentially, if fee_paid_date is before close date, then say"fee paid before closed" else "fee paid during open"

so here is what i did

```
main_df["Payment_validity"] = main_df['fee_paid_date'].apply(lambda x: 'Fee paid while open' if x <=main_df['PACKAGE_D_CLOSE'] else 'Fee paid after closed ')
```

and i get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use `axis=1` to tell do the `apply` row wise

```py
main_df["Payment_validity"] = main_df[['PACKAGE_D_CLOSE','fee_paid_date']].apply(lambda x: 'Fee paid while open' if x[1] <= x[0] else 'Fee paid after closed ', axis=1)
```

NOTE: assuming `PACKAGE_D_CLOSE` and `fee_paid_date` are `datetime` object not `string`.

You can cast them to `datetime` by simply

```
main_df['fee_paid_date'] = pd.to_datetime(main_df['fee_paid_date'])
main_df['PACKAGE_D_CLOSE'] = pd.to_datetime(main_df['PACKAGE_D_CLOSE'])
```